# How can verify if google chrome is logged in a site with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a extension for chrome. I have a site that has a list of affiliate sites. When a user access a site that is affiliate with my site i want that extension checks if chrome is already logged in my site and perform different actions if It is logged or not. How can i do?

Comment: oh sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

Every site handles user states differently. Most likely you need to evaluate the cookie or the DOM of the site. Every web application I've written uses encrypted cookies, many other sites do the same, so evaluating the DOM is most likely more fruitful. There cannot be a generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

The browser (any browser, not just Chrome) doesn't know about any "logged in" status for any site. Instead the browser maintains a list of cookies for particular sites that the user has visited (and accepted cookies for). One of the cookies for a particular site may mean (for *that* specific site) that the user is known under some specified identity, that may even be anonymous. Each site defines it's own set of cookies.

However, you are talking about "affiliate sites", meaning there is some relation between them and you. You might be able to require a specific cookie (readable from your plugin) that signals this status.